# Erro ao pegar valor retornado com query.getResultList().get(0)

Tags: java, jpql

Preciso pegar o valor de uma query, simplesmente um campo e estou tomando o seguinte erro:

> ```
> java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String.
> ```

Meu DAO está assim:

```
public String buscaCodColaborador() throws MetrusDAOException{
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
        sqlString
            .append(" SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9999 ")
            .append(" MINUS")
            .append(" SELECT COD_COLABORADOR FROM ME_COLABORADORES");

        em = getEntityManager();

        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sqlString.toString());

        String codColaboradorDisponivel = (String) query.getResultList().get(0);

        return codColaboradorDisponivel;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e, e);
        throw new MetrusDAOException(e);
    } finally {
        closeEntityManager(em);
    }
}
```

Preciso apenas pegar um valor do banco e setar posteriormente no meu Business o valor retornado em um campo `Long`. Já tentei usar o `FindFirst` do stream mas estou sempre tomando esses erros de conversão.

Comment: tá vindo um bigdecimal naquele get(0) ali esse erro esta acontecendo na hora da conversão,ao invés de dar o cast pra string é só dar um get(0).toString()...

Comment: Muito obrigado @LucasMiranda essa solução resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um *cast* só é possível quando os tipos envolvidos são compatíveis entre si, ou seja, quando um é subtipo de outro. Por exemplo:

```
class Animal { etc... }
class Gato extends Animal {
    // só gato fazem miau
    public void miau() { etc... }
}

Animal a = new Gato();
a.miau(); // erro: classe Animal não tem o método miau

// assim funciona
Gato g = (Gato) a; // fazendo cast para outro tipo compatível
g.miau(); // agora funciona
// ou ainda
((Gato) a).miau();
```

Quando as classes não tem relação de hierarquia entre si (uma não é subclasse da outra), o *cast* não é possível. É o caso de `String` e `BigDecimal`, daí o erro "*java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String*".

Se quer converter para `String`, uma maneira de fazer é simplesmente chamar [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString()):

```
String codColaboradorDisponivel = query.getResultList().get(0).toString();
```

---

Mas se esse valor é um número, não seria melhor o método `buscaCodColaborador()` retornar um `BigDecimal` (ou qualquer outro tipo numérico)? Você mesmo disse que depois precisa pegar "*o valor retornado em um campo Long*", então para que converter para `String`? Faça o método já retornar o tipo que você precisa. Por exemplo, se quiser que seja um `long`:

```
public long buscaCodColaborador() throws MetrusDAOException {
    ...
    BigDecimal codColaboradorDisponivel = (BigDecimal) query.getResultList().get(0);
    return codColaboradorDisponivel.longValue();
}
```